# Execute onload $(function () {} inside a timer, and pass parameter to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, timer

I have a onload function in jquery like:

```
$(function () {
    $('.over').hover(function () {

            //FIRST PARAMETER RIGT, LEFT, TOP, BOTTOM
        if ($(this).attr('data-direction') == 'right') {
            $(this).addClass('flipping-right');
        }   
        else if ($(this).attr('data-direction') == 'left') {
            $(this).addClass('flipping-left');
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('data-direction') == 'top') {
            $(this).addClass('flipping-top');
        }
                 //ETC.

    //SECOND gal1,gal2,gal3,gal4
    if ($(this).attr('gal') == 'gal1'){    
        img = $(this).find('img');
        setTimeout(function() {
           img.attr('src', arrFirstYellowCard[i]);
           i++;
           if(i > arrFirstYellowCard.length-1)
              i=0;
       }, 100);
    }

    else   if ($(this).attr('gal') == 'gal2'){    
        img = $(this).find('img');
        setTimeout(function() {
           img.attr('src', arrSecondPurpleCard[j]);
           j++;
           if(j > arrSecondPurpleCard.length-1)
              j=0;
       }, 100);
    }
```

I want a function to execute that function every second but with parameters in array like

```
var array_param = ["right,gal1","top,gal3","bottom,gal4","left,gal2","right,gal5"];
```

which are allowed combinations

I want like a timer so each parameter is called every second

```
var timer = $.timer($('.over').hover(array_param( 0 ) ), 1000);
timer.play();
```

but I do not know how to implement this function, and how to add parameters to a function allocated in onload :

`$(function () {     $('.over').hover(function () {...`

[Please take a look at my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUsPh/40/)

Comment: Instead of adding new event handlers every second, you should just change the array every second and reference that from the one handler.

Comment: could you please post a sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trigger ready again. You can create a named function and call it a bunch.

```
$(function () {
    index = 0;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (index > array_param.length) index = 0;
        myFunction(array_param[index++]);
    }, 1000); // call myFunction every second
});

myFunction = function (image) {
    $('.over').hover(function () {
        // rest of your code goes here
        ...
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means. I said _you can't trigger ready again_. It's not a matter of not needing to, it's not possible, it can only be triggered once.

Comment: how can I assign "right" to `$(this).attr('data-direction')` and gal1 to `$(this).attr('gal')` using the code you added ` myFunction(array_param[index++]);` in the function definition: myFunction = function (dir, gal), to simplify things I pass values directly but got no luck http://jsfiddle.net/fUsPh/45/

Comment: Sure, but why would that be relevant at all? You can hook on $.ready whenever you want, and it will get executed

Comment: I thought that's what the OP was asking for. Maybe I misunderstood his question. I though he was asking to trigger his code that happen in `$(function() {` (ready) every second.